# remove white space between nav and bannner

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to reduce the white space between the navigation bar and the banner.....
i reduced the padding and margin but its not getting affected....
providing my code below.....

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#" style="padding-top: 0px;">
            <img alt="change" class="defieLogo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/defie_logo_only.png">
          </a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/docs/examples/product.html">Product</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/solution.html">Solutions</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/service.html">Services</a></li>
              <li class="iphonePartnerLink"><a href="/docs/examples/partner.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li class="iphoneContactLink"><a href="/docs/examples/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav" id="navSecond">
              <li class=""><a href="/docs/examples/partners.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
              <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
            </form>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's great that you've posted a demonstration, but you should post a stripped down version, that only shows the elements in question. That way we don't have to sift through all of your code and resets to find what you're talking about.

Comment: @EricLemos: the banner is the image

Answer (score 2):

```
navbar .navbar-inner {
background: #fff;
color: #000;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-ms-border-radius: 0;
-o-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
text-shadow: none;
padding: 20px 0 10px;    <--- remove this
}
```

Comment: I updated in the fiddle but still its not working....how to fix it  http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/NsmtF/2/embedded/result/

Comment: there should not be any space between nav bar and banner image

Comment: I see no banner image - just a nav bar with a gradient.

Comment: i am talking about his one .home .hero-unit {
background: none;
height: 318px;
padding: 1px 620px 0 0;
margin-right: -100px;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-bottom: 0;
background: url("../images/defie_landing_page_new.png") right bottom no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 0):

Put following CSS rules at the end of your css. I think it will fix your problem.

```
.home { padding-top: 47px !important; }
.home article.container { margin-top: 0px !important; }
.navbar { height: 47px !important; }
.navbar .brand { padding: 0 20px 10px !imporatnt; }
```

You are using bootstrap responsive, check your page in smaller browser width.
Bootstrap is creating collapsible menu which doesn't seems good with the current background!

Also I would recommend you to not make changes on bootstrap files, it will make it impossible to update your libraries. Instead you can overwrite them.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/NsmtF/2/embedded/result  i updated in the fiddle but still not working

Comment: The image you have used in your header background is not visible to me. `http://v2.defie.com/images/defie_landing_page_new.png`. are you talking about space between your navbar menu and this element?

Comment: yes i am talking abt the space between this image and nav bar